# (R) Apply running row sums in a table object with 2 variables

Tags: r, dataframe, cumulative-sum

The following is a replicated sample of data which records the duration of 300 absences. `month` is the first month of the absence and `length` is the number of concurrent months the absence lasted.

```
df <- data.frame("month" = sample(c("jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"),300, replace = TRUE),
           "length" = sample.int(6, size = 300, replace = TRUE))

df$month <- factor(df$month, levels(df$month)[c(5,4,8,1,9,7,6,2,12,11,10,3)])
```

Using `table(df$length)` you can see how many separate absences lasted for exactly each value of `length`.

```
1  2  3  4  5  6 
55 45 42 56 51 51
```

But because `length` is incremental, if I wanted to show the total number of absences that reached (but not necessarily lasted) a certain number of months, I could use `rev(cumsum(rev(table(df$length))))` which gives:

```
 1   2   3   4   5   6 
300 245 200 158 102  51
```

I am interested in seeing this cumulative view by `month`. `rev(cumsum(rev(table(df$month,df$length))))`
returns a vector and not a table.

**The result I would like is to take this**

```
table(df$month, df$length)

       1  2  3  4  5  6
  jan  5  5  4  5  3  2
  feb  5  7  2  7  9  3
  mar  5  3  2  2  9  4
  apr  6  7  4  4  3 11
  may  5  5  3  5  5  2
  jun  4  4  2  7  4  5
  jul  4  3  5  5  1  4
  aug  4  0  5  3  6  7
  sep  4  5  4  4  3  3
  oct  4  2  1  6  5  4
  nov  5  2  3  5  2  2
  dec  4  2  7  3  1  4
```

**and turn it into this, where the reverse cumulative count of `length` is calculated for each `month`.**

```
       1   2   3   4   5   6
  jan  24  19  14  10  5   2
  feb  33  28  21  19  12  3
  mar  25  20  17  15  13  4
  apr  35  29  22  18  14 11
  may  25  20  15  12  7   2
  jun  26  22  18  16  9   5
  jul  22  18  15  10  5   4
  aug  25  21  21  16  13  7
  sep  23  19  14  10  6   3
  oct  22  18  16  15  9   4
  nov  19  14  12  9   4   2
  dec  21  17  15  8   5   4
```

Is there a way to do this using `table()`? If not, I am open to any solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowCumsums` on the `rev`erse columns using index with `seq` (`:`) reversed for the column index and then `rev`erse the index again

```
library(matrixStats)
tbl <- table(df$month, df$length)
tbl[] <- rowCumsums(tbl[, ncol(tbl):1])[, ncol(tbl):1]
tbl
#     
#       1  2  3  4  5  6
#  jan 24 19 14 10  5  2
#  feb 33 28 21 19 12  3
#  mar 25 20 17 15 13  4
#  apr 35 29 22 18 14 11
#  may 25 20 15 12  7  2
#  jun 26 22 18 16  9  5
#  jul 22 18 15 10  5  4
#  aug 25 21 21 16 13  7
#  sep 23 19 14 10  6  3
#  oct 22 18 16 15  9  4
#  nov 19 14 12  9  4  2
# dec 21 17 15  8  5  4
```

---

Or in `base R`, it would be `cumsum` with `apply`

```
tbl[] <- t(apply(tbl[, ncol(tbl):1], 1, cumsum))[, ncol(tbl):1]
```

#### data

```
tbl <-  structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    7L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
    6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 11L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L), .Dim = c(12L, 6L
    ), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", 
    "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"), c("1", "2", 
    "3", "4", "5", "6")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

Comment: I deleted my original comment after your edit. I got the outcome I hoped for afterwards. Thank you for the quick and brilliant response.

Comment: FYI, using `rowCumsums(tbl, cols=ncol(tbl):1)` is much more efficient (time and memory) than `rowCumsums(tbl[, ncol(tbl):1])`.  See `bench::mark(rowCumsums(tbl[, ncol(tbl):1]), rowCumsums(tbl, cols=ncol(tbl):1))` for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a data frame rather than a table-class object, you can use `Reduce` with `+` as the function and  `accumulate = T` to get a cumsum. Before creating the "table" (in quotes since the class is not "table") I made a factor version of the month column so the months would stay in the same order.

```
df$month_fac <- with(df, factor(month, levels = unique(month)))
tbl <- data.table::dcast(df, month_fac ~ length)
tbl[ncol(tbl):2] <- Reduce('+', rev(tbl[-1]),  accumulate = TRUE)
```

The output is the `tbl` object, but I didn't bother showing it because you didn't set a seed so the (random) values will be different from the output shown in the question.